# standard D types and GDC (LDC) specification

Tags: d, gdc

Where can I find specification about GDC (GNU D Compiler) and how to rewrite standard D types like uint etc.?

For info: I'm interested in using D for kernels and other low level stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow the D ABI specification: http://dlang.org/abi.html

GDC follows pretty much everything from the top down to 'Function Calling Conventions' section.

This page will tell you some of the same information: http://gdcproject.org/wiki/Porting

All I have to say on rewriting the standard D types is DON'T.  You are likely reaching the wrong solution for the wrong problem to be solved.  I suggest giving me a bell on IRC if you use that platform, as I'd be much more readily available to answer any GDC Dev queries there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "rewrite standard D types like uint".

You may find this useful, however: https://github.com/xomboverlord/xomb